# Tinymce Stripped out $ and '{' in elements

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I am using Codemirror to view the source code in tinymce , The problem is

This source code

```
<div name="Default" linespacing="22.34pt" style="text-align: center;" ${TEST}>
```

gets converted into- you can see. the attribute ${TEST} is replaced with test=""

```
 <div name="Default" linespacing="22.34pt" style="text-align: center;" test="">
```

So I don't want this to happen.

Comment: can you share the tinyMCE initialization code...

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti ,   Here is my tinyMCe initialization code - 

<code>
    tinymce.init({ ..
..
...
keep_styles: true,
convert_fonts_to_spans: false,
valid_elements: '*[*]',
elementpath: false,
 verify_html: true,
  custom_style_formats: customFontFormat,
  valid_children: "+body[style],+body[title],+body[center],+body[meta],+body[!--]" 
});
<code>

Answer (score 0):

on your initialization try setting `verify_html` to `false`, like:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    verify_html : false,
    ....
});
```